# Is it possible to run chat bot written in apps-script as "me"

Tags: google-hangouts

It is possible to deploy the app scripts projects as web apps and execute them as script owner ("Execute the app as me").

I don't see something like this for chat bots.

I looked here https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script#authorization

It would be nice to have something like in appscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "chat": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  }
}
```

Is it possible?

Update: created a feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74233022

Answer (score 1):

As of now Hangouts Chat currently does not have this feature. The best way to have this pushed to Hangouts Chat is probably by filing feedback via https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=350158&template=1047215 and hope that it gets enough upvotes.

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*. I can see *in this specific case*, that the same answer applies to two very different issues, but you could easily have been explicit about the feature missing.